# Rails rendering json on destroy not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render some specific json based on whether the destroy worked or not. However, the code gets past the `@attachment.destroy`... then throws an exception when it tries to render the json. Not sure what's going on here.

```
  def delete
    @attachment = Attachment.find(params[:attachment_id])

    if @attachment.destroy
      render json: {
        status: 200,
        message: MESSAGES_SUCCESS
      }
    else
      render json: {
        status: 422,
        message: MESSAGES_FAILED
      }
    end
  end
```

Comment: What is the exception? Can you show us the error?

Comment: so it turns out... it was a double render error. not sure why it would ever enter the second block though... unless `@attachment.destroy` always returns true

Comment: How are you making the call to the delete method ?

Comment: I just call `@model.destroy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destroy attachment and then check if there are any errors.

```
def delete
    @attachment = Attachment.find(params[:attachment_id])
    @attachment.destroy

    if @attachment.errors.any?
        render json: {
            status: :unprocessable_entity, # 422
            message: MESSAGES_FAILED
        }
    else
        render json: {
            status: :ok, # 200
            message: MESSAGES_SUCCESS
        }
    end
end
```